# Can't get ANTLR (Javascript target) accept Emoji in the input file

Tags: javascript, parsing, antlr4, emoji, lexer

My ANTLR lexer has below rules for a string.

```
string: STR | EMOJI ;
STR:   [0-9̈A-Za-z_"«»„“ʌɪˈ\p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement}]+
EMOJI: [\p{Emoji}]+ ;
```

What I don't understand is  has the unicode **U+1F600**. I believe the **\p{Emoji}** code set is a set of these unicodes. However, the input file I write has the UTF8 unicode for the same emoji that are totally different from the said unicode. You can see what they are like if you look at this page and hover over an emoji https://moji.clock-up.jp/emoji/.

As the result, my parser always fail when it encounters a emoji in the input stream.

FYI I use antlr4ts TypeScript runtime (https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts) instead of the regular antlr4 Javascript runtime.

Could you help me to figure out the way to have Emojis be parsed nicely?
Thanks!

Comment: After posting this question, I figured I should check with the regular Javacript runtime. Seems like it works fine with the regular runtime code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar works pretty well for me (also using the TS runtime in my extension):

[image]

Maybe it's something in the input handling, how you load the input? The correct approach is to use the (relatively) new CharStreams:

```
const input = CharStreams.fromString(source);
const lexer = new MyLexer(input);
```

where `source` is a normal JS/TS string.

Comment: Wow, it worked! Thank you so much. This is the best thing I have had this week 

Comment: Great to hear it helped you! Can you accept my answer then?